# How to check in a props file if the importing project is a .NET Core SDK project

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, csproj

How can i make a PropertyGroup(in a .props file) conditional on the kind(old/new format) of project which imported the .props file? 
( by new format I mean .NET Core SDK projects )

I've got a `Directory.Build.props` file in directory `root\`, which is implicitly imported to all projects under `root\`.
most projects use the new csproj format and some use the old format,
I want to add a `PackageReference` which breaks the old format projects,
I'd like to exclude the property in the old format projects.

I looked at [Common msbuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2017) and around the MS docs and didn't spot anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to define items instead of properties for package references, you can use conditions on an item group (or the items themselves) since all properties are evaluated before all items.

You likely also want to condition the reference not on the project "style" (SDK vs classic) but rather on the style of referencing NuGet packages - since you can also use `PackageReference` in classic projects instead of packages.config.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(RestoreProjectStyle)' == 'PackageReference'">
  <PackageReference Include="My.Pkg" Version="1.2.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```